# Dictionary in Array with String as key and Image as value

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var imagearray1 = ["AvengerPic1": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic1")!, "AvengerPic2": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic2")!, "AvengerPic3": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic3")!, "AvengerPic4": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic4")! ]
```

I have declared an array called imagearray1 . Every index has Dictionary value. I have created an imageview. how can I assign a image to that imageview? 
How to break an array with dictionary value?

Comment: `imagearray1` is a dictionary, it's not an array. Get the value by key.

Comment: var imagearray1 : ["String":uiimage] =[ ["AvengerPic1": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic1")!, "AvengerPic2": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic2")!, "AvengerPic3": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic3")!, "AvengerPic4": UIImage(named: "AvengerPic4")! ]]. Sorry about the miss writing. How can i 
Get image from the array.

Comment: anyway is a dictionary @VirenPatel its a dictionary with key : String and value as UIImage an array with dictionary values is declared this way `var imagearray1 : [[String:UIImage]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone has said `imageArray1` is not an array it is a dictionary.

To get the images and put in UIImageViews you can do the following:

```
    //1. Extract All The Image Values From The Dictionary
    let images = imagearray1.map { $0.1 }

    //2. Loop Through The Images & Set In ImageViews
    for index in 0 ..< images.count{

        let imageHolder = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 110 * index, width: 100, height: 100))
        self.view.addSubview(imageHolder)
        imageHolder.image = images[index]
    }
```

Comment: THank you. This will really help